# What is the 'OfOfPieChartArray' element?

Tags: apache-poi

In MS Powerpoint's APIs, there exists a class `CTPlotArea`. It has this function `sizeOfOfPieChartArray`

I am only able to locate this documentation of the API here: https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-cloud-service/implementing/developing/ref/javadoc/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/chart/CTPlotArea.html

[image]

It does not explain what is an OfPieElement?

I would like to know what is an `OfPieElement` and is the API `sizeOfOfPieChartArray` for. I am using `sizeOfPieChartArray` at the moment and the presence  of very similarly sounding API is confusing me.

Answer (score 2):

The `org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.CTOfPieChart` is the `XML` element for a pie chart having a smaller excerpt-chart at it's side. This can be a [pie-of-pie chart or a bar-of-pie chart](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/explode-or-expand-a-pie-chart-63284b67-22ea-4960-ab1e-0a3895af68ce?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#__draw_attention_to).

A pie-of-pie chart looks like so:

[image]

In a bar-of-pie chart the smaller excerpt-chart would be a bar chart instead.

`CTPlotArea.sizeOfOfPieChartArray()` returns the size of `OfPieChartArray`, thus how many pie-of-pie or bar-of-pie charts actually are present in the plot area.